# encrypting old data in database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jasypt

I have added this in my application context file

```
<!-- Added to encrypt user identification fields using jasypt -->
    <bean id="stringEncryptor"  class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
    <property name="password" value="contactKey" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="hibernateEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.hibernate.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor" lazy-init="false">
    <!-- This property value must match "encryptorRegisteredName" used when defining hibernate user types -->
    <property name="registeredName" value="jasyptHibernateEncryptor" />
    <property name="encryptor" ref="stringEncryptor" />
  </bean>`

This below coded added in hibernate mapping file
`<typedef name="encryptedString" class="org.jasypt.hibernate.type.EncryptedStringType">
        <param name="encryptorRegisteredName">jasyptHibernateEncryptor</param>
    </typedef>
```

We are using spring with Hibernate in to my application,but we want to implenting jasyptHibernateEncryptorin in to my application.

It's working fine when storing a new entry into database table and fetching the same entry, but problem here its how to encrypt my old data.

Answer (score 1):

you create a new app that connects to the database, fetches all the existing rows and updates them one by one after encrypting the fields with your encryptor. After this update is done you can use the new typedef to handle these encrypted fields.

Comment: I would like to know which encryption technique do i use. which same as jasypt encryption technique/how do i get old data which is not encrypted

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to elaborate more:

1. currently you mapped your entities/classes to a database with proterties NOT encrypted which looks something like this:

   @Entity

   public class Person {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private long id;
   private String name; 
   }

If you plan to swith to an encrypted type (jasypt) you need to first encrypt all the current
values in the database with a code that looks like this:

```
public class Exec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(true);
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sf.openSession();         


            //configure the jasypt string encryptor - different type use different encryptors
            StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
            encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            encryptor.setPassword("123456");
            encryptor.setKeyObtentionIterations(1000);          
            encryptor.initialize();
//                        get all unencrypted data from db and encrypt them - here just the name property of the Person is encrypted.
            session.beginTransaction();
                List<Person> persons = session.createQuery("select p from Person p").list();
            for(Person pers : persons){
                pers.setName(encryptor.encrypt(pers.getName()));
                session.save(pers);             
            }

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            } catch (Exception ex2) {
                ex2.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
            HibernateUtil.shutdown();
        }

    }
}
```

After you encrypted the values you need, switch the Person entity to use the encrypted type like this:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs({
    @org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(name="EncryptedString",
            typeClass=EncryptedStringType.class,
            parameters={@Parameter(name="algorithm",value="PBEWithMD5AndDES"),@Parameter(name="password",value="123456"),@Parameter(name="keyObtentionIterations",value="1000")})
})
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Type(type="EncryptedString")
    private String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
// ... getters and setters
}
```

Make sure that the parameters of the encryptors are the same in the definistion and in the code:
same algorithm, same password, same key obtenation iteration parameter.
After that you can use the Person entity as usual since the encryption is transparent to the java persistence code you use.

A working example of this code you can checkout from svn with this command:

svn checkout http://hibernate-jasypt-database-encryption.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ hibernate-jasypt-database-encryption-read-only

Good luck !